# max-height não está funcionando

Tags: html, css

Bom dia primeiramente. Estou tentando limitar a altura da minha `div` com classe `contacts` dentro da minha `div` com classe `contact-page`, porém a altura da `contacts` excede a `contact-page`, mesmo com o `max-height`.

A ideia é um quadro de contatos que respeite o elemento pai, com uma rolagem na vertical

---

Eu poderia simplesmente inserir uma div em volta do `contacts` que irá funcionar da forma que espero, mas o meu objetivo é entender o por que isso acontece(do max-height não funcionar) e resolver de forma simples pelo css

---

```css
.container {
  max-height: 300px;
  background: #dddddd;
}

.contact-page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.contact-page div {
  max-width: 45%;
}

.contacts {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="contact-page">
    <div class="address">
      <p>Responsável: José</p>
      <p>Cidade: Cataguases - MG</p>
      <p>Bairro: Bairro</p>
      <p>Endereço: Rua SP, 115</p>
      <p>CEP: 36773-582</p>
      <p>GMAP Plus Code: JAZV+Q7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contacts">
      <div class="contact">
        <b>Contato local</b>
        <p>(32) 3421-1202</p>
      </div>
      <div class="contact">
        <b>Sr.(a) José</b>
        <p>Contato 1: (32) 99810-0006</p>
        <p>Contato 2: (32) 92000-8962</p>
        <p>Email: ddwres@gmail.com</p>
      </div>
      <div class="contact">
        <b>Sr.(a) Geraldo Benjamin Davi da Cunha</b>
        <p>Contato 1: (62) 3888-2057</p>
        <p>Contato 2: (62) 99959-7885</p>
        <p>Email: geraldobenjamindavidacunha-83@live.se</p>
      </div>
      <div class="contact">
        <b>Sr.(a) Kauê Filipe Levi Baptista</b>
        <p>Contato 1: (61) 3690-1697</p>
        <p>Contato 2: (61) 99945-5650</p>
        <p>Email: miguelkevinmelo_@tita.com.br</p>
      </div>
      <div class="contact">
        <b>Sr.(a) Danilo Manuel Martins</b>
        <p>Contato 1: (32) 3421-8588</p>
        <p>Contato 2: (32) 98986-7429</p>
        <p>Email: danilomanuelmartins-98@numero.com.br</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é que na classe "pai de todos" que é a `div.container` vc colocou `max-height`, e na verdade deveria ser um valor fixo só `height: 300px` mesmo. Pois na div  filha direta `div.contact-page` vc usou `max-height: 100%`, mas para pegar o 100% do pai ele precisa ter um valor fixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  background: #dddddd;
}

.contact-page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.contact-page div {
  max-width: 45%;
}

.contacts {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="contact-page">
    <div class="address">
      <p>Responsável: José</p>
      <p>Cidade: Cataguases - MG</p>
      <p>Bairro: Bairro</p>
      <p>Endereço: Rua SP, 115</p>
      <p>CEP: 36773-582</p>
      <p>GMAP Plus Code: JAZV+Q7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contacts">
      <div class="contact">
        <b>Contato local</b>
        <p>(32) 3421-1202</p>
      </div>
      <div class="contact">
        <b>Sr.(a) José</b>
        <p>Contato 1: (32) 99810-0006</p>
        <p>Contato 2: (32) 92000-8962</p>
        <p>Email: ddwres@gmail.com</p>
      </div>
      <div class="contact">
        <b>Sr.(a) Geraldo Benjamin Davi da Cunha</b>
        <p>Contato 1: (62) 3888-2057</p>
        <p>Contato 2: (62) 99959-7885</p>
        <p>Email: geraldobenjamindavidacunha-83@live.se</p>
      </div>
      <div class="contact">
        <b>Sr.(a) Kauê Filipe Levi Baptista</b>
        <p>Contato 1: (61) 3690-1697</p>
        <p>Contato 2: (61) 99945-5650</p>
        <p>Email: miguelkevinmelo_@tita.com.br</p>
      </div>
      <div class="contact">
        <b>Sr.(a) Danilo Manuel Martins</b>
        <p>Contato 1: (32) 3421-8588</p>
        <p>Contato 2: (32) 98986-7429</p>
        <p>Email: danilomanuelmartins-98@numero.com.br</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito, entendi como funciona, agradeço demais!!

Comment: @JoséAugustoMegres legal que pegou a ideia ai, abs